# What is $\csc^{-1}(\csc 0)$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse-function

We have been taught that $\csc^{-1}(\csc 0)$ is undefined, as $\csc 0$ is not defined. But when I graphed it on desmos, $\csc^{-1}(\csc x)$ was defined on $x = 0$ and was equal to $0$.

Same is the case for $\sec^{-1}(\sec x)$ at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Can someone explain this discrepancy? Thank you.

Comment: Since $\csc 0$ is undefined (it is infinite, which is not a real number), so it doesn't lie in the domain of $\csc^{-1}$. But in graph plotting, it is basically taken to be the identity map.

Comment: Mathematica gives $0$ as the result

Comment: A general comment: I am always surprised to the importance that is given in certain countries to $\sec, \csc, \csc^{-1}$ etc. In my country, France, and, as far as I know, in many countries of continental Europe, we only use $\sin, \cos, \tan$ and sometimes $cotan$. I don't say at all that we are a model ! But I think that having too many circular functions blurs things.

Comment: @JeanMarie In india, we worship them.

Comment: @samjoe I appreciate your humor.

Comment: @JeanMarie. Same for me (from the same country as you are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, we have $\csc^{-1}(\csc(x))=x$ *except* when $x=0$, where it is undefined. The reason the graph makes it look like it is defined at $0$ is because you can't see one point being excluded from a curve, unless it is intentionally labeled.

As $x$ approaches $0$, $\csc(x)$ approaches $\pm \infty$, and so $\csc^{-1}(\csc(x))$ approaches $0$.

Answer (score 2):

These kinds of identities, where a function that would normally not be defined at a certain point is instead defined as a particular value, show [removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity). $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\csc^{-1}\csc x$ is 0 and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi/2}\sec^{-1}\sec x$ is $\pi/2$; by defining the values of these functions at these removable singularities as these limits, the functions become regular around those points.